# Transform JSON loaded geometry to a curve geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I have a geometry loaded from a JSON. Now, I need to transform this geometry into a curved geometry. The extent of the curve depends on a point in the space. For eg. the current geometry lets say is in (0,0,0) and then there is another geometry in (10,10,10) (the user will specify this and will vary) and then the curve of the geometry will be calculated.

[image]

Another example: A normal geometry:
[image]

I want to achieve a similar curve of the above geometry:
[image]

JSON:

```
{
"normals":[0.433884,0.900969,0,0.974928,0.222521,0,0.781831,-0.62349,0,-1.099e-07,-1,0,-0.781832,-0.62349,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,-0,1,-0.433884,0.900969,0,-0.974928,0.222521,0,-0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1],
"vertices":[0,10,-0.5,0,10,0.5,7.81832,6.2349,-0.5,7.81832,6.2349,0.5,9.74928,-2.22521,-0.5,9.74928,-2.22521,0.5,4.33884,-9.00969,-0.5,4.33884,-9.00969,0.5,-4.33884,-9.00969,-0.5,-4.33884,-9.00969,0.5,-9.74928,-2.22521,-0.5,-9.74928,-2.22521,0.5,-7.81832,6.2349,-0.5,-7.81832,6.2349,0.5],
"colors":[11383485,16711935,0,11449278],
"faces":[161,0,1,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,161,2,3,5,4,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,161,4,5,7,6,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,161,6,7,9,8,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,161,8,9,11,10,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,160,5,3,1,5,5,5,1,1,1,160,1,13,11,5,5,5,1,1,1,160,11,9,7,6,6,6,1,1,1,160,7,5,1,6,6,6,1,1,1,160,1,11,7,7,7,7,1,1,1,161,1,0,12,13,8,8,8,8,0,0,0,0,161,10,11,13,12,9,9,9,9,0,0,0,0,160,12,0,2,10,10,10,0,0,0,160,2,4,6,11,11,11,0,0,0,160,6,8,10,12,12,12,0,3,0,160,10,12,2,12,12,12,0,0,0,160,2,6,10,12,12,12,0,0,0],
"metadata":{
    "normals":13,
    "generator":"io_three",
    "colors":4,
    "vertices":14,
    "version":3,
    "type":"Geometry",
    "faces":17
}}
```

I am a newbie with THREE.JS and graphics in general. My apologies, if i sound vague.

However, would appreciate if you can advise how I can get the curve?

Comment: I think you need some more explanation, and possibly an example to clarify.

Comment: What is the nature of the geometry you are loading, what is the nature of the transform, and what (precicely) do you mean by a curved geometry?

Comment: @Euan, hope it clarifies now.

Comment: MUCH better.  I'm not a three.js master either, but now there is a better chance of somebody being able to help you, either me or somebody who actually knows what they are talking about ;)

Comment: Why don't you create your curved geometry in a content creation tool like Blender, export it as `glTF` and just load it? Modifying geometries within your app via a generic algorithm is tricky, especially if you have to develop the modifier by yourself. And since you are new to `three.js` and computer graphics, I would not recommend this approach.

Comment: Thought about it. The extent of the curve depends on a point in the space. For eg. the current geometry lets say is in (0,0,0) and then there is another geometry in (10,10,10) (the user will specify this) and then the curve of the geometry will be calculated. I should note it down above. Any suggestions in this use case?